# Rewrite URL based on form input

Tags: url-rewriting, forms, rewrite-rules

I have a form:

```
<form action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" method="get">
<select name="genres[]">
<option value="jazz"></option>
<option value="blues"></option>
<option value="rock"></option>
</select>
</form>
```

After submitting the form, in the URL the input becomes `example.com/?genres%5B%5D=jazz&genres%5B%5D=blues&genres%5B%5D=rock`

Next to that it doesn't look very nice, I have other inputs in my form (and around 18 genres) so if a user selects a lot, the URL becomes very long.

I'm not very skilled in wordpress rewrite rules. I'd like the URL to become `?genres=jazz,blues,rock` but I would also be satisfied if just the characters won't be ASCII code, so the url becomes `?genres[]=jazz&genres[]=blues&genres[]=rock`. I'm also using the array (`$genres = $_GET['genres']`) as input for a query so if I alter it, it should still be usable as an array. That's why I think just rewriting the ASCII codes to characters is the best option.

Comment: that's not really a URL rewrite, you're just reformatting a get request. also- square brackets are not legal characters in URIs, so your desired structure is not possible.

Comment: how is it wordpress related?

Comment: This is how `GET` works in forms. Had you considered using `POST` instead? It would make more sense than trying to bend this with WP rewrites or something.

Comment: Good to know that square brackets are not allowed in URLs. I can use `POST`, but it's nice for users to share the URL and get the same results.